# Vue pass value of inputfield, and the reference to the object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a v-for loop that displays an input field for each ingredient, on change of that input field I would like to update a value on the ingredient object.

```
<div
      v-for="ingredient in ingredients"
      v-bind:key="ingredient.id"
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        :value="calculateGrams(ingredient)"
        @input="onIngredientInput(ingredient)"> <-------------
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to send the reference to the object I want to change, and the value of the input field that it has to change to. The following code only shows the output of the first argument, it's not sending the event.

```
methods: {
    onIngredientInput (e, ingredient) {
      console.log(e, ingredient)
    }
  }
```

**What is the easiest way to change a property on the object in the loop, to the value of that input field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@input="onIngredientInput($event, ingredient)
```

Comment: Aha thanks, is this, in your opinion the best way to go about this action?

Comment: yes. If you wish to pass an event param to a custom event handler just use a special $event object.

Answer (score 0):

you may use watch preoperty to track your preoperty and make changes :

```
:value=changedIngredient
watch: { changedIngredient:function(value){

// make your changes 
}
}
```